# How to refresh Google "accessToken" using "refreshToken" on the client

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, google-oauth, expo

I have a React Native app that is using `Expo.Google.logInAsync` to login via Google. This returns an `accessToken` (expires after 1 hour) and a `refreshToken`.

Im passing this `accessToken` to the Firebase Web SDK:

```
const cred = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(null, accessToken);
await firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(cred).catch(console.error);
const idToken = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true).catch(console.error);
```

How should I be using this Google `refreshToken` to keep the Firebase `idToken` valid and logged in after one hour?

Should I make the request below and re-reun the Firebase `signInWithCredential`?

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#exchange-authorization-code

```
POST /oauth2/v4/token HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=<your_client_id>&
client_secret=<your_client_secret>&
refresh_token=<refresh_token>&
grant_type=refresh_token
```

I can get my `client_secret` from the Google API Credential page. Most people say to keep it on the server if possible, but some say you can also embed it into your client code if needed.

**Is the `client_secret` designed to be used from client side code in a phone app?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase sessions are indefinite. Firebase Auth returns an ID token and refresh token after sign in and every time an ID token expires, the refresh token is used to get a new ID token. The client SDK will take care of the refresh on its own. You just call `getIdToken()` and it will either returned the cached ID token if not expired or retrieve a new one using the underlying refresh token. The Google OAuth refresh token you are referring to is not needed here.

Comment: Thankyou Sir, makes perfect sense!

Comment: @bojeil What if you want to refresh the access token, not the id token?

Comment: Firebase Auth does not issue access tokens. If you mean third party access tokens from IdPs you sign in with (Google, Facebook, etc), Firebase Auth does not manage that after sign in.

Comment: is that  underlying refresh token provided for react-native-firebase as well ? @bojeil

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clarified the Google OAuth Token is not be able to refreshed via Firebase Auth flow nowadays ?